# how to take data from redux in index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i have index.js 
that takes the routes from 
root .
i need to access the store and get the variable navigate 
needs to be true after log in 
and initialy it is false

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { HashRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import ReduxThunk from "redux-thunk";
import allReducers from "./Reducers";
import Root from "./root";

const store = createStore(allReducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
const loggedin = true;
ReactDOM.render(<Root store={store} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

the root.js file is :

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { HashRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Full from "./containers/Full/";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
// Views
import Login from "./views/Pages/Login/";
import Register from "./views/Pages/Register/";
import Page404 from "./views/Pages/Page404/";
import Page500 from "./views/Pages/Page500/";

const Root = ({ store }) => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <HashRouter>
            <Switch>
                {/* <Route
                    exact="exact"
                    path="/login"
                    name="Login Page"
                    component={Login}
                /> */}
                <Route
                    exact="exact"
                    path="/register"
                    name="Register Page"
                    component={Register}
                />
                <Route exact="exact" path="/404" name="Page 404" component={Page404} />
                <Route exact="exact" path="/500" name="Page 500" component={Page500} />
                {/* <Route path="/" name="Home" component={Full} /> */}
                <Route
                    path="/"
                    render={() =>
                        this.props.navigate ? (
                            <Route component={login} />
                        ) : (
                            <Route component={Full} />
                        )
                    }
                />
            </Switch>
        </HashRouter>
    </Provider>
);
Root.propTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
const mapStateToProps = ({ authRed }) => {
    const { navigate } = authRed;
    console.log("navigation system ready:", navigate);
    return { navigate };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(Root);
```

my console log in mapstate to props i returning the exact needed data 
but if i use this.props.navigate error occurs 
cannot read property 'props' of undefined

does anyone have a solution ??

Comment: Where do you add the line with `this.props.navigate`?

Comment: i used this.props.navigate in root const 
<Route
                    path="/"
                    render={() =>
                        this.props.navigate ? (
                            <Route component={login} />
                        ) : (
                            <Route component={Full} />
                        )
                    }
                />

Comment: Does `this.props.navigate` works outside of Route `render` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your root component is a `functional component` and doesn't have a `this` keyword, you need to `destructure` props and use it, just like you did `store`

```
const Root = ({ store, navigate }) => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <HashRouter>
            <Switch>
                {/* <Route
                    exact="exact"
                    path="/login"
                    name="Login Page"
                    component={Login}
                /> */}
                <Route
                    exact="exact"
                    path="/register"
                    name="Register Page"
                    component={Register}
                />
                <Route exact="exact" path="/404" name="Page 404" component={Page404} />
                <Route exact="exact" path="/500" name="Page 500" component={Page500} />
                {/* <Route path="/" name="Home" component={Full} /> */}
                <Route
                    path="/"
                    render={() =>
                        navigate ? (
                            <Route component={login} />
                        ) : (
                            <Route component={Full} />
                        )
                    }
                />
            </Switch>
        </HashRouter>
    </Provider>
);
```